# Neon: isnan(val) intrinsics

Tags: arm, simd, neon, cortex-a8

I want to use `isnan()`functionality in NEON intrinsics .Below is my code :input1,input2 and output is of type float .These values are getting updated from ROI of input image/frame.(image processing example)

```
for(x = 0;x<ht;x++){
for(y = 0;y<width;y++){
float a  = (input1[x + (y * width)]);
float b  = (input2[x + (y * width)]);
// check for division by zero
output = 0.0f;
if (!(isnan(a) | isnan(b) | (b == 0)))
{
        output[x + (y * width)] = a / b;
}
}
```

}

By using newton Raphson method I tried to do division by using neon intrinsic .
But i am not able to get any intrinsics for `isnan` .I got  `__builtin_isnan`() which is is not an intrinsics .How Can I use `isnan` for `float32x4_t a` and `float32x4_t b`

Comment: in this case you are telling like check a == a ,which is true every time .so how can this work as isnan ??

Comment: Paul R,Can you please elaborate by giving small example .It will helpful for me .

Comment: @PaulR  sqrt(-1) = sqrt(-1)  ?? This condition can you explain me  with your logic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A useful property of IEEE-754 floating point values is that comparing two NaN values always returns false. You can use this property to test for `NaN`, as follows:

```
bool isNaN(float x)
{
    return !(x == x);
}
```

This same test can be applied to SIMD operations, where a float vector may be compared with itself, and the result will be false for any element which is a `NaN`, e.g.

```
float32x4_t vx = { ... };

uint32x4_t vcmp = vceqq_f32(vx, vx);
```

The elements of `vcmp` will be `true` (`UINT_MAX`) for non-`NaN` values in `x`, and `false` (`0`) for any `NaN` values.